# How can I get Symfony request context to use the REQUEST_URI from a IIS rewrite rule?

Tags: symfony, url-rewriting, iis-7, reverse-proxy

I setup a Reverse Proxy Rewrite Rule in IIS7 for requests to Symfony.
It matches the pattern and passes the correct request details so from a technical perspective it is working, but Symfony doesn't seem to use the correct info or rather the info I want it to use.

Breakpointing in `app.php` to see what symfony receives from the other server in the `$_SERVER` details the relevant parameters for this are:

- `HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL="/foo/bar/foo/someCall/123456789"`
- `REQUEST_URI="/bar/foo/someCall/123456789"` (what was matched by the
  pattern in the rewrite rule)

A route has been setup for `/bar/foo/someCall/{id}`, but the request context only sets the `pathInfo` as `/foo/bar/foo/someCall/{id}`, which results in a "No route exists ..." error.

I need the request context (possibly route listener etc) to use what is in `REQUEST_URI`. How would one be able to do so, if at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS generates the header `HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL` as part of the rewrite and unfortunately Symfony will overwrite the `REQUEST_URI` due to the condition for `if ($this->headers->has('X_ORIGINAL_URL'))` in the `prepareRequestUri()` funtion.

Leading off from what Pierre spoke of in his answer he assisted in figuring out how to get around the problem.

We had to adapt our nginx conf file to 'overwrite' the `HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL` to be empty so the condition was not met and the `REQUEST_URI` is not incorrectly overwritten.

```
location ~^\/{url}\/? {
    ...
    proxy_set_header X-ORIGINAL-URL "";
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using a reverse proxy, you shouldn't change your application to match your proxy url (or even be aware that is is running behind a proxy). Instead the proxy needs to ensure it send the correct information to your application. In order to do that, you need to understand how Syfony decides if a route matches or not.

Symfony by default uses the `REQUEST_URI` to determine a route. But it also supports IIS rewrite rules, which then overwrite the `REQUEST_URI` value, which can be seen here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L1684-L1717. So just working with the `REQUEST_URI` won't work here.

In this case, the interesting part is the way Symfony determines the base URL (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L1729-L1752). Since you are trying to rewrite the base of the URL, your best bet would be to manipulate the script path that is passed as part of the proxy. I'm not an expert in IIS or how it's rewrite rules work, but when using Nginx as a reverse proxy, you normally would set the `X-SCRIPT-NAME` header to your base path, so you can try something similar in IIS.

Comment: Thank you very Pierre much for the explanation and additional info on how Symfony would handle requests and rewrites. :)